# asp.net store object class in viewstate (or other ideas)

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

I've build a class like this:

```
private class TestResults
{
    public bool IsAdmitted { get; set; } 
    public bool IsDuplicate { get; set; } 
    public bool IsVerified { get; set; } 
}
```

The values of this class are set at postback by clicking a radiobutton list. Problem however is I don't know  how to save this values across multiple postbacks. I thought of using viewstate but I'm not quite sure how to do it with this class.

Maybe I'm missing some important thing here.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction

thanks for your time!
Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: It would be good if you could accept some more answers, assuming there are some correct ones of course. This will help you build reputation and it will encourage users to answer your questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just sticking this class in viewstate is pretty simple:

```
ViewState["SomeUniqueKey"] = myTestResults;

var testResults = (TestResults)ViewState["SomeUniqueKey"];
```

Your class will need to be marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute though.

Answer (score 1):

try using the Session cache instead

```
 var testResults = new TestResults();
 //set values
 Session["TestResults"] = testResults;
```

Retrieving them later on:

```
 var testResults = Session["TestResults"] as TestResults;
 if (testResults != null)
 {
      //use it
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel excactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You are welcome Mark. Would you mind marking the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Session.Add("TestResults", Your_Test_Result_Object)
```

[Session Object Explanation](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/57/session/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need this value on other pages or in other places throughout the app, you can use viewstate.

Use the `Page.ViewState` object bag to store it:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page {
    protected void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ViewState["myObject"] = testResultsObject;
    }
}
```

You could also wrap the access to it in a property on the page:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page {
    public TestResults TestResults { 
        get{ return ViewState["TestResults"] as TestResults; }
        set{ ViewState["TestResults"] = value; }
    }   
}
```